# Complexity to determine the size of an Erlang's binary

Tags: erlang, complexity-theory

I know that, for a list, we have to traverse the entire list and then determine the size of it?

What is the complexity to determine the size of a binary in Erlang?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`byte_size/1` (the command to measure binary stuff) executes in constant time irrelevant to the size of the binary, while length of a list is proportional to the size of the list.

[See 3 Common Caveats for reference](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/commoncaveats.html)

Answer (score 4):

Time and memory complexity of `erlang:size/1`, `erlang:tuple_size/1`, `erlang:bit_size/1` and `erlang:byte_size/1` is O(1). (And `erlang:map_size/1` as well.) Why do you even think it could be anything else? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The binary data structure stored in the process heap is a REFC header that contains the binary size, So byte_size execute in a constant time.

Comment: *Why do you even think it could be anything else?* Because you can loop over a binary just like you can a list?  Isn't that like asking: Why would you think that length() is anything but O(1)?

Comment: @7stud: Loop over binary? How and why you loop over binary. I don't get it. I think you don't know what binary is. The list is a chain of pieces, you have to loop over to get the length. It is called the length for a reason. When the size is just a measurement of one piece of continuous block of memory. What is exactly what binary is.